# Excel VBA Class Object Gets Undefined

Tags: excel, vba

I have centralised the handling of all events in my Excel workbook in a single class called "Components".
The class is moved to a separate "xlam" file and that "xlam" file referenced in the Excel workbook.

Class "Component" is defined as follows:

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "Components"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True
Attribute VB_Exposed = False

Public WithEvents WorkbookSD As Workbook, _
       WithEvents SheetConfig As Worksheet, _
       TableConfig As ListObject, _
       TableVerValues1 As ListObject, _
       TableVerValues2 As ListObject, _
       TableDValues As ListObject, _
       TableIGRValues As ListObject
...

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
  On Error GoTo ErrorHandling
  ToggleAppUpdate False
  Set WorkbookSD = ActiveWorkbook
  Set SheetConfig = WorkbookSD.Worksheets(SHEET_CONFIG)
  Set TableConfig = SheetConfig.ListObjects(TABLE_CONFIG)
...

Private Sub SheetConfig_Activate()
  On Error GoTo ErrorHandling
  ...
ErrorHandling:
  If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    ReportError
  End If
End Sub
```

Notice that "Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True" in order to ensure that an object of class is declared. Sort of like how a Form does it.

So I declare all the objects for which I want to handle events in this class and WithEvents.
"Component" is initialised in the "Class_Initialize" event.

I reference objects and methods from this class by "Component.XXXX" elsewhere in the code. Here is an example from another module in the "xlam" file:

```
Public Function FindCnfg(pTerm As String, pSearchBy As SearchBy) As Range
  Dim lTable As ListObject, _
      lRow As Range, _
      lCol As Long
  On Error GoTo ErrorHandling
  Set FindCnfg = Nothing
  Set lTable = Components.TableConfig  
  If lTable.DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
    Exit Function
  End If
  Select Case pSearchBy
    Case SearchBy.ID
      lCol = 1
    Case SearchBy.Key
      lCol = 2
    Case Else
      RaiseError ErrorCode.INVALID_PARAM
  End Select
  Set lRow = lTable.DataBodyRange.Columns(lCol).Find(What:=pTerm, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows)
  If Not lRow Is Nothing Then
    Set lRow = lRow.EntireRow
    Set FindCnfg = lRow
  End If
ErrorHandling:
  Set lTable = Nothing
  Set lRow = Nothing
  If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    RaiseError Err.Number, "FindCnfg", Err.Description
  End If
End Function
```

I catch errors everywhere using "On Error GoTo X".

It all works well under normal circumstances and events are handled.

But every now and then, I get an error stating that the object "Component" is undefined or the event handling stops working alltogether without warning or error.

It works again if I manually enter the developer tool and run a method which references "Component".

I suspect that the issue has to do with the initialisation of the pre-declared "Component" object.

Does anyone have an idea about how to prevent these sporadic instabilities?
Perhaps a different approach which ensures that an object of "Component" is always available.

Comment: The code between `VERSION 1.0 CLASS` and `Attribute VB_Exposed = False` is no valid VBA code. Do you see that code part in the VBA-Editor? Please clarify. • Can you please also provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @peh looks like an export of the class module to me. Not visible in the IDE, but valid if you look at the expoted file in a text editor

Comment: @chrisneilsen yes I saw that, that's why I asked if he sees that code part in VBE. Because I have seen people exporting modules and instead of importing them correctly the opened the file in notepad and copied the content. My question aimed to make sure that this did not happen here.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ: It is as "chris neilsen" describes. It is an export. I added an event handling example above. The rest of the "Components" class is pretty straight forward. Just the usual event handling.

Comment: I wonder whether the the class is being initialised before the workbook is fully loaded, leading to some undefined behaviour. You could try manually creating the class in your workbook_open event; possibly even with `Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "CreateComponentClass"` to ensure everything is ready. Depending on where you create the object, you might need to declare the variable globally and include a factory method in your `.xlam`, since classes in add-ins can at best be `PublicNotCreatable`.

Comment: @Greedo Two things here: 1- I tried having a global variable for "Component" initialised in a Public Sub. But that had the same symtoms too. General instability. 2- The current class is not "PublicNotCreated". It is "Private". Could this causing some of the issues?

Comment: Oh no, the instancing just determines whether projects that reference your add-in can declare variables of that type; you would only need it if your global variable was held in the workbook not the add-in, it should have no bearing on the bug. Try the time delay if your workflow permits it. Otherwise, I would try and identify what actions and conditions lead to the behaviour. As you can probably imagine some code fragments and undefined errors aren't much to go on!

Comment: I think there is a syntax error in line Set lTable = Components.TableConfig  Else. You can't use Else there.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the issue has multiple root causes.
1- The global variables get undefined.
2- Office 2016 has multiple bugs including in Workbooks.Open (which I use in my code).

To resolve 1, I replace the global variable with a function that returns the variable and use that function instead of the global variable:

```
Private lComponents As Components

Function MyComponents() As Components
  If lComponents Is Nothing Then
    Set lComponents = New Components
  End If
  Set MyComponents = lComponents
End Function
```

To resolve 2, do not assign the return value of Workbooks.Open to any variable.
Instead, call Workbooks.Open and then assign the variable to Workbooks(nameOfWB):

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:=lPath
Set WB = Workbooks(nameOfWB)
```

These two changes have greatly improved stability. I no longer have random errors due to undefined variables.